# Converting a JSON object into a response object

Tags: javascript, json, jasmine, aurelia

I am trying to pass mock JSON data into my jasmine unit test.

The format of my JSON is like the one below:

```
{   
   "CompanyResponse":{    
      "CompanyCreatedDate":"1990-10-02",    
      "RunDate":"2",   
      "LastChangedDate":"2015-10-02",   
      "CompanySummary": {   
         "Id":"Apple",   
         "MaximumCredit":"10000000",   
         "Margin":"60000000",    
         "Limit":"-1500000",    
         "HistoricData":{    
            "CompanyHistoricData": [   
               {  
                  "LaunchDate":"2008-08-31",  
                  "Product":"Iphone2",  
                  "TotalProductsCreated":"1000000",  
                  "TotalProductsSold":"800000",  
                  "TotalReturns":"200000",  
                  "TotalMargin":"600000"  
               },  
               {  
                  "LaunchDate":"2010-08-31",  
                  "Product":"Iphone4",  
                  "TotalProductsCreated":"2000000",  
                  "TotalProductsSold":"1500000",  
                  "TotalReturns":"350000",  
                  "TotalMargin":"800000"  
               }  
            ]  
         },  
         "RefurbishedData": {  
            "CompanyRefurbished": [  
               {  
                  "Id":"Apple.201221.12",  
                  "ProductId":"iph-213454",  
                  "StartDate":"2015-09-07",  
                  "FinishDate":"2015-09-10",  
                  "CostOfRefurbishing":"50"  
               },  
               {  
                  "Id":"Apple.201228.12",  
                  "ProductId":"iph-4155655",  
                  "StartDate":"2015-09-10",    
                  "FinishDate":"2015-09-12",  
                  "CostOfRefurbishing":"85"  
               }  
            ]  
         }  
      }  
   }  
}
```

I am using the above JSON to pass on to a function similar to the one below for unit testing:

```
public getTotal(response: CompanyResponse): void {    
  var companySummary = response.CompanySummary;    
  
  //gets total 'CostOfRefurbishing' for all phones    
  var totalRefurbishmentAmount :number = 0;

  for (let companyRefurbishments of companySummary.RefurbishedData) {
    totalRefurbishmentAmount += Number.parseInt(companyRefurbishments.CostOfRefurbishing.toString());
  }
}
```

---

The problem I am facing is that I am not able to pass `CompanyResponse` as a whole to the `getTotal()` function. It doesn't work even if I use `JSON.stringify()` because it just converts it to a string and it doesn't work if I use `JSON.parse()` either as it converts it back into the Object format.

Here's how we call the `getTotal()` method in a normal scenario:

```
export class MyService{    
 async CompanySummary(): Promise<CompanySummaryResponse>    
{    
    const response = await this.http.fetch('CompanySummary');    
    return await response.json();    
  }    
}    

var myService = new MyService();    
CompanySummary: CompanySummaryResponse;    
CompanySummary = await myService.CompanySummary();    
this.calculator.getTotal(CompanySummary);
```

Cheers,
Guru

Comment: Where is `Reallocations` in your data?

Comment: You need `CompanyResponse` to have a constructor that takes that object, or something derived from that object, as parameter

Comment: @torazaburo sorry my bad. its RefurbishedData in the JSON, not Reallocations

Comment: @arboreal84 , this is a part of unit testing and I am trying not to restructure my program in order to make the unit test work.  In the real scenario its an HTTP call that gives me the real response JSON.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Can you use the [standard Response Interface from the JavaScript Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) to mock a response object?

If you look at the [documentation for the constructor method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/Response) - it accepts a `body` parameter and an `init` options object. The `body` parameter can be a Blob, so you could;

```
var data = {foo: "bar"};
var blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)], {type : 'application/json'});

var init = { "status" : 200 , "statusText" : "SuperSmashingGreat!" };
var myResponse = new Response(blob, init);
```

This would create a `Response` object that you should be able to pass to your test.

Comment: Tried the above approach, the issue is still the same. The getTotal function complains about not being able to accept the parameter  of type "Response"

Comment: @GuruduttShenoy When you use `getTotal` normally - what is passed to it?

Comment: Have added a normal call to the getTotal() along with the service call through which it gets the JSON data in the last part of my question posted above.  https://stackoverflow.com/users/297243/thebluefox

Comment: . the issue is resolved now. the issue was actually with passing of the parent element 'CompanyResponse' as a part of the JSON file. Returns the expected Response with the standard response interface from FetchApi you mentioned earlier. Thanks a lot for your help :) https://stackoverflow.com/users/297243/thebluefox

Comment: My pleasure @GuruduttShenoy - glad you got it sorted!