# Use Axios instead of Fetch with Cache API

Tags: javascript, axios, browser-cache, cacheapi

I am successfully using `fetch` to download an image file and store in a custom cache:

```
await fetch(url).then( async (response) => {
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new TypeError("Bad response status");
  }

  return cache.put(url, response);
});
```

I would like to switch this to `axios` so I can display download progress and stop the download if needed. I am able to successfully download the file:

```
await axios({
  method: 'get',
  url: url,
  responseType: 'blob'
}).then( async (response) => {
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new TypeError("Bad response status");
  }

  return cache.put(url, response);
});
```

But it returns and error: `Failed to execute 'put' on 'Cache': parameter 2 is not of type 'Response'.`

Referencing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44037816/converting-a-json-object-into-a-response-object) I also tried to manually create the response:

```
var init = { status: 200 , statusText: 'OK', type: 'cors', url };
var myResponse = new Response(response, init);
return cache.put(url, myResponse);
```

But it seems to override the other information and doesn't store the blob data at all:

[image]

Is axios able to create the type of response that is needed for the Cache API?

Edited to add: I've also tried changing the `responseType` to `stream` which is what `fetch` seems to return, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Why do you not use axios-cache-adapter ? (https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-cache-adapter)

Comment: @Amirhossein hoping not to use another library; I'm trying to store really large files so was working with the Cache API directly

Comment: Have a look at https://axios-cache-interceptor.js.org/